# Angular- adding parameters to http.get calls

Tags: angular

I am very new to Angular(started today) and I'm simple trying to extend a tutorial from datafiles to the Django REST Framework and API calls.  I cannot work out how to pass a variable to an http call to a Django Rest Framework api.

I have my app module / route specified thus:

```
import { BarDetailsComponent } from './bar-details/bar-details.component';
const routes: Routes = [
  ...
  { path: 'bar-details/:id', component: BarDetailsComponent },
  ...
]
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ...
    BarDetailsComponent,
    ...
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes),
    HttpModule
  ],
  providers: [
    ...
    BarDetailsProvider,
    ...
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

**BarDetailsComponent**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Bar } from '../bars/bar';
import { BarDetailsProvider } from './bar-details.provider';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-bar-details',
  templateUrl: './bar-details.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./bar-details.component.scss']
})
export class BarDetailsComponent implements OnInit {

  bar: Bar;
  private selectedId : number;

  constructor(private barDetailsProvider: BarDetailsProvider) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.barDetailsProvider.getBarDetails().subscribe(bar => this.bar = bar);
  }

}
```

**BarDetailsProvider**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Bar } from '../bars/bar';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { environment } from '../../environments/environment';

@Injectable()
export class BarDetailsProvider {

  constructor(private http: Http) { }

  getBarDetails(): Observable<Bar> {
    return this.http.get(`${environment.baseUrl}/bar/1`).map(response => response.json() as Bar);
  }
}
```

Where I have `return this.http.get(`${environment.baseUrl}/bar/1`).map(response => response.json() as Bar);` above I want to replace 1 with the id which gets passed from the following html

```
<h1>Bars</h1>
<div *ngFor="let bar of bars">
  <a routerLink="/bar-details/{{bar.pk}}">
    <h2>Name: {{bar.name}}</h2>
  </a>
  <div>Address: {{bar.address}}</div>

  <hr>
</div>
```

How do I get the `id` I'm passing back into the `get` call?

Comment: Have a look at https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/routing/routeparams.html#reading-route-parameters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yea, you need to subscribe to your route param schanges into your component

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

ngOnInit() {
     this.sub = this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
          const id = params['id'];

          this.barDetailsProvider.getBarDetails(id).subscribe(bar => this.bar = bar);
     });
}
```

and change your service accordingly

```
getBarDetails(id: string): Observable<Bar> {
    return this.http.get(`${environment.baseUrl}/bar/${id}`).map(response => response.json() as Bar);
```

}

Comment: this gives me the error `Property 'sub' does not exist on type 'BarDetailsComponent'.`

Comment: )) you need to create it, this is just a variable. I thought it obvious

Comment: I'm really new to Angular.  I've put it in as a variable `sub: Subscription` (I don't know if that is right) which generates js error "Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined"

Comment: you see this `route` in my code. this is ActivatedRoute class, and you need to add this into your constroctor. I'll edit my answer. @HenryM i'll explain all you need if you want.

Answer (score 0):

1 way - when you change id in routing end update them (with subscribe)

**BarDetailsComponent**

```
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
....
constructor(private activeRoute: ActivatedRoute ..... {
   this.activeRoute.params.subscribe(element => {
     this.id = element['id']; //you get id
     this.barDetailsProvider.getBarDetails(this.id).subscribe(bar => this.bar = bar);
   })
   ....
}
```

2 way - without subscribe
**BarDetailsComponent**

```
this.id = this.activeRoute.params['id']
```

in *getBarDetails()* function add id param

```
getBarDetails(id): Observable<Bar> {
    return this.http.get(`${environment.baseUrl}/bar/${id}`).map(response => response.json() as Bar);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

asuming your path would be like this

```
{path: 'bar-details/:id', component: BarDetailsComponent}

export class PopDetailsComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
private subscription: Subscription;
constructor(private actRoute: ActivatedRoute){
this.subscription = this.actRoute.params.subscribe(
   (params: any) => {
   if (params.hasOwnProperty('id') && params['id'] != '') {
      this.fooId = params['id'];
 });
}
// dont forget to unsubscribe
 ngOnDestroy() {
  if(this.subscription) {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }
 }
}
```